# Comparing an Arc2D with a Component

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I have a quick question for you guys, well, quick for you, not quick for me.

I have an array that is filled with Arc2D shapes and I have a MouseAdapter

Within the mousePressed event, I need to compare the clicked Arc2D with the array of Arc2D's, or even better, automaticly identify which Arc2D was clicked and then be able to work from there on (change the color, more specificly)

I tried this

```
private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         Point p = e.getPoint();
         Component c = gamePanel.getComponentAt(p);

         if(c == arcs[0]) {
             System.out.println("test");
         }
     }
}
```

of course that doesn't work, but I honestly have no idea what to do

thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT:

After looking at the first answer I got on here, I tried to change the code to this

```
private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         Point p = e.getPoint();

         if(arcs[0].contains(p)) {
             System.out.println("test");
         }
     }
}
```

of course that won't work because the arcs array only contains the arcs that are later drawn in this method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graph) {
    super.paintComponent(graph);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graph;
    // smooth graphics
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // moving to the middle of the panel
    g.translate(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);

    // painting colored arcs
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        g.setColor(dimColors[i]);
        g.fill(arcs[i]);            
    }

    // painting borders
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5F));
    g.drawLine(-98, 0, 98, 0);
    g.drawLine(0, -98, 0, 98);      
    g.draw(circle);     

    // painting central white circle
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fill(smallCircle);        
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.draw(smallCircle);    

}
```

I am completely stuck guys

Comment: *"I have a quick question for you guys.."*  Unfortunately the only answers I have for you are not quick, so ..never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here this may get you started...

```
private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point click = e.getPoint();
        //this next loop may seem hacky
        for (Arc2D c: arcs) {
            if (c.getX() == click.getX() && c.getY() == click.getY()) {
                System.out.println("The arc at (" + c.getX() + ", " + c.getY() + ") was clicked.");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No arcs were clicked.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that gives a type mismatch (Component and Arc2D) same problem I was working on at first

Thanks anyways!